# How to validate exposed autocomplete to select values from list only?

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, views, forms

I have custom module with the following code, but I have no idea to validate the exposed auto-complete field to select values only from the list. Any ideas on how to validate the exposed auto-complete field ?

```
function advanced_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state,$form_id) {

if($form_state['view']->name == 'propertyseach') {

$form['bed']['#options']['All'] = t('Bed'); // overrides <All> on the dropdown
$form['section']['#options']['All'] = t('Type'); // overrides <All> on the dropdown
$form['bath']['#options']['All'] = t('Bath'); // overrides <All> on the dropdown
$form['furnished']['#options']['All'] = t('Furnished'); // overrides <All> on the dropdown
$form['frontprice']['min']['#title'] = '';
$form['frontprice']['max']['#title'] = '';
$form['frontprice']['min']['#attributes']['placeholder']= t('Min.Price');
$form['frontprice']['max']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Max.Price');
        $form['frontprice']['min']['#size'] = '10';
        $form['frontprice']['max']['#size'] = '10';
        $form['frontprice']['min']['#maxlength'] = '10';
        $form['frontprice']['max']['#maxlength'] = '10';

$form['community']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Enter Location (City or Community )'); 
$form['#validate'][] = '_your_custom_validation';
}
    drupal_set_message($form_id);
        }



function _your_custom_validation($form, &$form_state){
  //validate stuff, using form_set_error()
}
```

Comment: which field has autocomplete functionality and what kind of field is it, eg, text, nid, numeric, location id, etc?

Comment: @Jimajamma it taxonomy  with text field,sorry im on mobile now.

Comment: I don't have a vanilla d6 box nearby, the only one I have readily available uses the content_taxonomy module, but its autocomplete widget can be set up to not allow new terms to be added.  so you may want to download it off drupal.org and take a look at the logic inside there.  otherwise, in your validate you will obviously have to look at the `$form_state['values']['YOUR_FIELD']` array info and check to see if it is a valid tag name and then complain if not. I can probably talk at great length about this on chat sometime tomorrow if need be.